# Jump to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the following jQuery code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').delegate('.page-scroll a', 'click', function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $( "#test" ).append('<div class="page-scroll"><a href="#im-dynamic">Test Dynamic</a><div id="im-dynamic">Dynamic</div></div>');  

});
```

And this HTML...

```
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <div class="page-scroll">

            <a href="#im-not-dynamic">Test Non Dynamic</a>
            <div id="im-not-dynamic">Non Dynamic</div>

        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

When I click on the following link, it jumps as expected.

```
<a href="#im-not-dynamic">Test Non Dynamic</a>
<div id="im-not-dynamic">Non Dynamic</div>
```

But when I click on the following link, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined." which references the "scrollTop" line above. How do I make the im-dynamic div element visible in the DOM, assuming this is the problem?

```
<a href="#im-dynamic">Test Dynamic</a>
<div id="im-dynamic">Dynamic</div>
```

EDIT: Just for clarification, I can see the dynamic elements fine. They are being created. For some reason, JS appears to be unable to see the im-dynamic div element, and is creating that error.

Comment: And where/how you created such dynamic element?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm using jQuery's append method

Comment: What is `$(this)`? body? or `.page-scroll a`? I'm not that great jQuery, I use JavaScript more.

Comment: @zer00ne $(this) references the clicked link. ".page-scroll a" is a contextual selector. In this case my link is contained within a div that has a .page-scroll class. I didn't include that div here, because I didn't want to clutter up the code. Like I said, the first link works, the listener for the dynamic link works with no problem, but the dynamic div itself (i.e. where it's supposed to jump to) appears to not be recognized by JS.

Comment: Check my answer and test the snippet please

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I edited my question to include how the dynamic elements are created.

Comment: @zer00ne Sorry, I just edited my question to include how the dynamic elements are created, in case this is relevant. Your snippet doesn't include that.

Comment: @JimSmith Ah, much better, sir. try this: `$('body').on('click' '.scroll-page a', function(event) {....`

Comment: @JimSmith it looks like my answer works on the dynamic element...but I get an error on the non-dynamic...I think. Take a look, I changed it to conform to your answer's code.

Comment: @zer00neI put the original listener back in, and it still works fine. Sadly, though it works here where I've provided the bare essentials, I still can't get my code to work. I have to look at it closer in the morning to try to isolate what's going on. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @zer00ne Ok I'm embarrassed to say that the dynamic target I created accidentally included the "#" in the name. So, basically I did this. newtarget.attr('id', ‘#im-dynamic') instead of this newtarget.attr('id', ‘im-dynamic'). Sorry. I wasted your time. Hopefully you picked up a thing or two in the process :-/

Comment: @JimSmith Indeed I did, the differences between `.delegate` and `.on`